# How to let one component correspond with the other for a specific function

Tags: html, json, vue.js, vue-component

I've got a component where I click a color of a machine, when I change colors, the machine gets loaded with a different color inside a image carousel.

Now I also created a component in the bottom with a image gallery of the same machine. How can I make it that the image gallery also changes color when I click the color button in the top of the page?

Important notice: The two components are not in the same parent component but they do load in the same machine images already, so the methods are not wrong I believe.

this is the clickable color button:

```
 <li
            v-for="(color, index) in machine.content[0].machine_colors"
            :key="color.color_slug"
            v-if="color.inStock"
            v-on:click="selectColor(index)"
            v-bind:class="{ active: (color.color_slug === selectedColor.color_slug)}">
            <img v-bind:src="color.color_dash">
          </li>
```

this is the component that changes color:

```
<div class="product__carousel">
      <Carousel showIcon v-if="selectedColor" :machineColor="selectedColor"/> <!-- Image carousel gets loaded in -->
    </div>
```

and the component that needs to change color but does not:

```
<div id="tab-two-panel" class="panel">
           <footerGallery  v-if="selectedColor && machine" :machineColor="selectedColor"/>
      </div>
```

Heres the script of the partent component:

```
export default {
name: 'aboutMachine',
components: {
  Collapse,
  footerGallery,
},
data() {
  return{
    selectedColor: this.getMachineColorContent(),
  }
},
props: {
  main: {
    default () {
      return {};
    },
  },
  machine: {
    default () {
      return {};
    },
  },
},
 methods: {
getMachineColorContent() {
  if (this.selectedColor) {
    return null;
  }
  return this.machine.content[0].machine_colors[0];
},
selectColor(index) {
  this.selectedColor = this.machine.content[0].machine_colors[index];
},
```

},
  }
and the component itself:

```
export default {
name: 'footerGallery',
props: {
  showIcon: Boolean,
  machineColor: {
    default () {
      return {};
    },
  },
},
data() {
  return {
    highLightedThumbIndex: 0,
    isActive: undefined,
  };
},
created() {
  this.highLightedThumbIndex = this.highLightedThumbIndex || 0;
},
methods: {
  selectThumb(index) {
    this.highLightedThumbIndex = index;
  },
},
```

};

This is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueYouTubeEmbed from 'vue-youtube-embed'

import FontAwesome from './libs/fa';
import App from './App';

const eventHub = new Vue();
Vue.use(VueYouTubeEmbed);
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesome);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use events to accomplish this. The [migration guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced) to Vue2 has a good short explanation of how to do simple event routing without using a full Vuex solution. In your case, you would declare a global event hub in one of your js files:

```
var eventHub = new Vue();
```

In your selectColor method you would emit the index selected:

```
selectColor(index) {
    this.selectedColor = this.machine.content[0].machine_colors[index];
    eventHub.$emit("select-color",index);
}
```

And in the footer, you would register a listener for the select-color event that calls selectThumb with the payload of the event (which is the selected index):

```
created() {
    this.highLightedThumbIndex = this.highLightedThumbIndex || 0;
    eventHub.$on("select-color",this.selectThumb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do I put all this code in my main.js or a new file with an instance? Because my main.js is global and already has a new vue defined

Comment: You should put the eventHub declaration in main.js (you will have two Vue instances, but that is ok). The other javascript snips are modifications to your existing code. Make those modifications in whatever file those methods appear in.

Comment: Got it! Will try this out today. Thank you very much.

Comment: When I try to add the eventhub globally it says it is declared but never used. Do I have to import it somewhere? I changed my question to provide you the code

Comment: If you haven't modified the functions with the lines I added, it won't be used. I'm not sure about declaring it as const either.